# JavaFX for Android - gradle build property not found

Tags: java, android, mobile, javafx, gradle

I am using [this](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20and%20deploying%20JavaFX%20Applications) guide to try and port my JavaFX application to Android.

I have downloaded and installed all the things that the guide says I need but when I run the command:

`gradle -PDEBUG -PDIR=/home/josh/cs335Android -PNAME=AndroidTimeline -PPACKAGE=src -PJFK_SDK=/home/josh/android-sdk -PJFX_APP=/home/josh/git/TimelinePhaseTwo -PJFX_MAIN=src/gui/Driver createProject`

it says:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project '***android-tools***'.
Cause: Could not find property '***ext***' on task '***:conf***'."
```

I think this is because I am not properly supplying the parameters to gradle (as described in the guide) but I don't actually know how to do that. Are those something that I write in the build.gradle file?